# REACT NATIVE - Trigger Modal on App Screen using a Custom Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am trying to trigger on the App Screen a modal using a custom button component.

I created a reusable button named **SelectBoxLong.js**

[image]

```js
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.containerLong} onPress={onPress}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="menu-down" size={10} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Also, I created a modal component named **FilterModal.js** which includes the useState that triggers the modal:
[image]

```js
const FilterModal = ({ text, onPress }) => {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = React.useState(false);
```

on the **App Screen**, I included the  component and the FilterModal But I can't manage to make a connection between this 3.

What I want is that when the user taps on the SelectBoxLong the modal triggers the modal, and the header of the modal gets the title of the button

[image]

**I Tried**

-Create a function inside Modal that triggers Modal

-Pass as props the useState

Answer (score 1):

App screen:

```
const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = React.useState(false);
const [buttonTitle, setButtonTitle] = React.useState(‘’);

onPress = () => {
  setModalVisible(true);
}


render(){
    return(
        ……
        <SelectBoxLong.js onPress={onPress} text={text}/>
        <FilterModal modalVisible={modalVisible} onPress={onPress} text={buttonTitle} />
        ….
    );
}
```

FilterModal.js

```
const FilterModal = ({ modalVisible , text, onPress }) => {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = React.useState(modalVisible);


  useEffect(() => {
    setModalVisible(modalVisible);
  }, [modalVisible]);
```